# How to make Workmanager on ios flutter

Tags: flutter

I worked a project to run a workmanager to make the application run in the background while the user was outside the application. The problem is now the application on Android is running, but with it running in iOS and an emulator on the Mac, the following problem appears:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel be.tramckrijte.workmanager/foreground_channel_work_manager)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:12)
#2      Workmanager.initialize (package:workmanager/src/workmanager.dart:100:30)
#3      _MyHomePageState.initState (package:toios/main.dart:58:17)
#4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4684:58)
#5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
#6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
#7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
#8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5874:14)
#9      Element.inflat<…>
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method registerPeriodicTask on channel be.tramckrijte.workmanager/foreground_channel_work_manager)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:12)
#2      Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask (package:workmanager/src/workmanager.dart:158:32)
#3      _MyHomePageState.initState (package:toios/main.dart:63:17)
#4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4684:58)
#5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
#6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
#7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
#8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5874:14)
#9<…>
```

And the complete code pages are as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';
import 'package:toios/notification.dart' as notif;

const fetchBackground = "fetchBackground";

void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    switch (task) {
      case fetchBackground:
        //Geolocator geoLocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager = true;
        Position userLocation = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
        notif.Notification notification = new notif.Notification();
        notification.showNotificationWithoutSound(userLocation);
        break;
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // We don't need it anymore since it will be executed in background
    //this._getUserPosition();

    Workmanager.initialize(
      callbackDispatcher,
      isInDebugMode: true,
    );

    Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(
        "1",
        fetchBackground,
        frequency: Duration(minutes: 30),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Notification {

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  Future showNotificationWithoutSound(Position position) async {
    print(position.toString());
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        '1', 'location-bg', 'fetch location in background',
        playSound: false, importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High);
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new IOSNotificationDetails(presentSound: false);
    var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'Location fetched',
      position.toString(),
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: '',
    );
  }

  Notification() {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }
}
```

Does anyone know to solve a problem to run it on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

ios doesn't support periodic task that is the cause of the error can only use one  off tasks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).